# Actionmailer on Redmine outputs error "certificate verify failed (self signed certificate)" on email send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, actionmailer, redmine, redmine-plugins

I updated a Bitnami Redmine package from version 4.2.1-0 to version 5.0.2-2.

I successfully migrated all data to the new server, but now the actionmailer doesn't work anymore.

When I try to send a test message, an error message "An error occurred while sending mail (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate))" appears.

Our mail server requires no tls or authentication at all so I have tried to disable tls in the configuration, but that has made no difference.

Configuration for the action mailer is the same one, that works on 4.2.1-0:

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: false
      address: smtp.myCompany.com
      port: 587
```

Comment: I am also having same problem.  did you find any solution

Comment: @Mukun sadly not yet, I had to revert back.

Answer (score 0):

put settings in production section not in default section